# process dies upon opencv_apps hough_circles.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

... logging to /home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/roslaunch-nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w-23082.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
]2;/opt/ros/indigo/share/opencv_apps/launch/hough_circles.launch
[1mstarted roslaunch server http://127.0.0.1:48358/[0m

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /hough_circles/accumulator_threshold: 50
 * /hough_circles/canny_threshold: 200
 * /hough_circles/debug_view: True
 * /hough_circles/dp: 2
 * /hough_circles/gaussian_blur_size: 9
 * /hough_circles/gaussian_sigma_x: 2
 * /hough_circles/gaussian_sigma_y: 2
 * /hough_circles/max_circle_radius: 0
 * /hough_circles/min_circle_radius: 0
 * /hough_circles/use_camera_info: False
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
    hough_circles (opencv_apps/hough_circles)

[1mROS_MASTER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:11311[0m
]2;/opt/ros/indigo/share/opencv_apps/launch/hough_circles.launch http://127.0.0.1:11311
core service [/rosout] found
[1mprocess[hough_circles-1]: started with pid [23106][0m
[31m[hough_circles-1] process has died [pid 23106, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/opencv_apps/hough_circles image:=image_rect image:=/hsrb/head_rgbd_sensor/rgb/image_raw __name:=hough_circles __log:=/home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1.log].
log file: /home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1*.log[0m
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
[1mdone[0m
```

This happens with a undiclosable robot's gazebo. `rostopic echo` with the aforementined topic returns good series of topics.

Looking into a log, the node seems to have launched once, and suddenly died without leaving meaningful error logs.

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,703: load_parameters starting ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,710: ... load_parameters complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,710: launch_nodes: launching local nodes ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,710: ... preparing to launch node of type [opencv_apps/hough_circles]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,710: create_node_process: package[opencv_apps] type[hough_circles] machine[Machine(name[] env_loader[None] address[localhost] ssh_port[22] user[None] assignable[True] 
timeout[10.0])] master_uri[http://127.0.0.1:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,711: process[hough_circles-1]: env[{'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'indigo', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/nao', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_
SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/devel/share/common-lisp', 'CPATH': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/devel/include:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/include:/opt
/ros/indigo/include', 'LOGNAME': 'nao', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 'PATH': '/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/home/nao/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/
local/games', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '/run/user/1000/keyring-yswdPa', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/devel:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo:/opt/ros/indigo', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/nao/hsr
_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/lib:/home/nao/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib', 'LANG': 'ja_JP.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PAT
H': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/nao/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'ja', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1963,unix/nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w:/t
mp/.ICE-unix/1963', 'SHLVL': '1', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c2', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'JOB': 'dbus', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a
8643/roslaunch-nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w-23719.log', 'TEXTDOMAIN': 'im-config', 'ROS_HOME': '/home/nao/.ros', 'WINDOWID': '65011723', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=fcitx', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': '
http://127.0.0.1:11311', 'ROS_HOSTNAME': '127.0.0.1', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/keyring-yswdPa/gpg:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/nao', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'fcitx', 'SELINUX_INIT': 'YES', 'COMPIZ_BIN_PATH': '/u
sr/bin/', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'fcitx', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/li
b/python2.7/dist-packages', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'VTE_VERSION': '3409', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring-yswdPa/ssh', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/indigo/shar
e/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'TEXTDOMAINDIR': '/usr/share/locale/', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/', 'TARGET_IP': '', 'ROS_PAC
KAGE_PATH': '/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/ar_track_alvar:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/hsr_seminar_2016:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/hsrb_controller_config_gazebo:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/hsrb_description:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/hsrb_gaz
ebo:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/hsrb_moveit_config:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/visualization_rwt/rwt_utils_3rdparty:/home/nao/hsr_ws/src/visualization_rwt/rwt_speech_recognition:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/share:/opt/tmc/ros/in
digo/stacks:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/db
us-38YuhJyGvY', '_': '/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubunt
u/upstart-session/1000/1811', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '1806', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:
su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.
gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=
01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=
01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf
=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01
;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'GDM_LANG': 'ja',
 'GTK_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module', 'INSTANCE': '', 'PWD': '/home/nao/hsr_ws', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'fcitx', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros', 'COLORTERM': 'gnome-terminal', 'DISPLAY':
 ':0', 'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'gnome-', 'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH': '/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/share/tmc_gazebo_worlds/models:/opt/tmc/ros/indigo/share/tmc_gazebo_worlds/models', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/us
r/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'USER': 'nao'}]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,784: process[hough_circles-1]: args[[u'/opt/ros/indigo/lib/opencv_apps/hough_circles', 'image:=image_rect', u'image:=/hsrb/head_rgbd_sensor/rgb/image_raw', u'__name:=h
ough_circles']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,784: ... created process [hough_circles-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: ProcessMonitor.register[hough_circles-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: ProcessMonitor.register[hough_circles-1] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: ... registered process [hough_circles-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: process[hough_circles-1]: starting os process
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: process[hough_circles-1]: start w/ args [[u'/opt/ros/indigo/lib/opencv_apps/hough_circles', 'image:=image_rect', u'image:=/hsrb/head_rgbd_sensor/rgb/image_raw', u
'__name:=hough_circles', u'__log:=/home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1.log']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,785: process[hough_circles-1]: cwd will be [/home/nao/.ros]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,791: process[hough_circles-1]: started with pid [23738]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,791: ... successfully launched [hough_circles-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,791: ... launch_nodes complete
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,791: registrations completed <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139670588589824)>
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,792: ... roslaunch parent running, waiting for process exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:58,792: spin
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,882: [hough_circles-1] process has died [pid 23738, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/opencv_apps/hough_circles image:=image_rect image:=/hsrb/head_rgbd_sensor/r
gb/image_raw __name:=hough_circles __log:=/home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1.log].
log file: /home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1*.log
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,882: ProcessMonitor.unregister[hough_circles-1] starting
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,882: ProcessMonitor.unregister[hough_circles-1] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,883: all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,983: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139670588589824)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,983: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 139670588589824)>: remaining procs are []
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,985: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,985: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,993: process monitor is done spinning, initiating full shutdown
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: runner.stop()
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: shutting down processing monitor...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: shutting down processing monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139670588589824)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139670588589824)>
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: ... shutting down processing monitor complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: done
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, stopped daemon 139670588589824)>
[rospy.core][INFO] 2016-10-11 15:24:59,994: signal_shutdown [atexit]
nao@nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w:~/.ros/log/latest$ more /home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1.log
/home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1.log: File not found
nao@nao-HP-EliteBook-8570w:~/.ros/log/latest$ more /home/nao/.ros/log/7d02daea-8f75-11e6-ac99-c8cbb85a8643/hough_circles-1-stdout.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245451/process-dies-upon-opencv_apps-hough_circles.launch/) by [kobalab](https://answers.ros.org/users/28210/kobalab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I took a look at @kobalab's computer and worked this issue around by re-installing `libopencv*` (and the dependent ROS packages).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0